# MySQL query summing records for users

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL with phpmyadmin -- which I only started to use today. If y'all can help me with this query you will create some major happiness:

My objective: to identify which users of status "userEnabled" have >3 records from the goals table associated with them.

`userID` is a field that relates the tables.

TABLE NAMES: `users`, `goals`

I think this would be the beginning of the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `userEnabled`=1
```

Please let me know any details needed.

Comment: do you mean where userenabled = 1 and its count is greater than 3?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join record from goals where the userid matches. Filter on the enabled flag, then count the results. Something like:

```
select * from users
    INNER JOIN goals ON users.userID = goals.userID
WHERE user.userEnabled = 1
GROUP BY user.userID
HAVING count(user.userID) > 3
```